# List all names in the database in kivy app

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating an app and I want it to list all the names, email, sector, and creation date of all users in the database. 
For now, it is just showing the info of the current user. This is the python code

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
n = ObjectProperty(None)
created = ObjectProperty(None)
email = ObjectProperty(None)
current = ""
sector= ObjectProperty(None)

def logOut(self):
    sm.current = "login"

def on_enter(self, *args):
    password, name, created, sector = db.get_user(self.current)
    self.n.text = "Account Name: " + name
    self.email.text = "Email: " + self.current
    self.created.text = "Created On: " + created
    self.sector.text = "Sector: " + sector
```

This is the corresponding kivy file

```
<MainWindow>:
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'back2.jpg'

n: n
email: email
created:created
sector:sector

FloatLayout:
    Label:
        id: n
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
        size_hint:0.8, 0.2
        text: "Name: "
        color: 0, 0, 1, .5

    Label:
        id: email
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.7}
        size_hint:0.8, 0.2
        text: "Email: "
        color: 0, 0, 1, .5

    Label:
        id: created
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.5}
        size_hint:0.8, 0.2
        text: "Created: "
        color: 0, 0, 1, .5

    Label:
        id: sector
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.3}
        size_hint:0.8, 0.2
        text: "Sector: "
        color: 0, 0, 1, .5
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is **where exactly** exactly are you having issue, your question is not descriptive enough